# Bootstrap h tag alignment with row class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I am trying to align a heading on top of form elements using bootstrap. And have the following code:

```
<div class="container">
   <h4>Heading</h4>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
         1 of 2
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The output in jsfiddle.net is as follows:

[image]

Why isn't the Heading left aligned with the div below it?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not reproducible. Please provide more context, like your **CSS** or included libraries.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
   <h4>Heading</h4>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
         1 of 2
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If your run this above snippet, you can see that "1 of 2" has the same alignment.
In fact, the `row` class has a **-15px margin** right and left. But the `col` class has a **+15px padding** right and left.